# How can I gain access permissions as a user to a USB stick formatted with the "Format Volume" dialog?

Tags: nautilus, usb-drive, format

I used the *Format Volume* dialog to format a USB stick. However, if I then insert the formatted stick, I have no permissions to access it as normal user.

Is this behaviour intentional?

*Format Volume*

[image]

*Permissions*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is completely normal as you are not the owner root is (root ran the application that you used to format the drive.) You can gain permissions again by opening a terminal and running `sudo chmod 666 /dev/sdx`  (where sdx = the location of the drive.)